# to use circular progress bar as alertdialog or progressdialog

Tags: android, wear-os, progressdialog

I am using this library to create a circular progress bar for my android wear (https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress).
I have created a layout in which circular progressbar is defined.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id = "@+id/progress_layout_id">
    <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
        android:id="@+id/m_arc_progress"
        android:layout_width="214dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want this layout in which circular Progressbar is defined to pop up as an alertdialog or a progress dialog. I was able to do this. This is the code for that.

```
public class progressbar_fragment extends AlertDialog {
    ArcProgress m_arc;
    View v;
    int mProgressVal;
    Context mContext;

    protected progressbar_fragment(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    m_arc = (ArcProgress) findViewById(R.id.m_arc_progress);


    if (mProgressVal > 0) {
        setProgress(mProgressVal);
    }
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    setContentView(R.layout.pogress_bar);
}
```

And I am calling it within class file as

```
    m_arc = new progressbar_fragment(m_caller_context);
    m_arc.show();
```

So the circular progressbar appears as alertdialog. Now I want to set progress as it goes through the code. Can anyone please guide me how I can do this set progress function is there in the library code.

There should be some way like

```
m_arc_progress = (ArcProgress) l_progress_layout.findViewById(R.id.m_arc_progress);
    m_arc_progress.setProgress(0);
```

At times it just works for initial case and when I try to do

```
m_arc_progress.setProgress(25);
```

It shows me error

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null
> object reference
```

Please help what to do.

Comment: Omg. What with the naming. It's very hard to read. Check naming convention for android

Answer (score 1):

you have set `setContentView(R.layout.pogress_bar);`after the dialog is shown you have to set it in onCreate() before you do a findViewById

Comment: But still how can I change the setprogress value as the code progress. Because I cant call onCreate every time right